# Azure VM for ETL tasks? Easy to automate start/end?

Tags: azure

I wanted to know how feasible it would be to schedule the start and shut down of an Azure VM which would handle some of the batch processing of raw data to prepare it for a database.

Is it a simple matter scheduling the VM to activate and then adding a shutdown script at the end of my scheduled tasks (I am using Python, primarily)? If so, I assume this is efficient for daily batch processing, but what about per hour or even smaller increments? I am hoping this is a cheaper solution compared to buying a beefy physical workstation.

I had a local system fail over the Christmas break which was pretty inconvenient. Also, a lot of tasks, raw files, and code are spread out over several physical machines which makes it tough for a coworker to fix if I am not around.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Azure Batch seems a good solution

With a simple auto scale formula, you can spin VMs on demand to reduce operation cost. It also has built in job scheduler and supports python.

Learn more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-python-tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling

Comment: @downvoter: Downvoting without a comment is a very impolite act

Comment: I am not sure who downvoted you, but thanks for the link. I was unaware of these services.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a script to run on a shceduled basis, then go for Azure Automation, Azure Functions or Azure Web Jobs. The latter is not recommended if you don't have a web site with Always On enabled.

It offers scheduling and running a script, EXE or whatever you need to accomplish.

If you have a requirement to use a VM, then do it and schedule a script with Azure Automation to turn on and off the VM on a scheduled time.